# Access to many databases with JpaUtil

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, dao

I am working on a java application with JPA and I need to access to many databases.
With only one database, I use to connect with JpaUtil

```
public class JpaUtil {

    public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "DBASE1";

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocalEntityManager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>() {

        @Override
        protected EntityManager initialValue() {
            return null;
        }
    };
...
```

So using many persistence unit could be a good solution to access to many databases ?
In this case, what should I do to avoid creating many JpaUtil classes for each database (I mean to have only one JpaUtil and give it the Persistence Unit as parameter)

Thank you very much